# Atomic Increment not updating value

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I am using following code to atomically increment DynamoDB update_counter field value by one.
But it always set update_counter to 1.

```
    inputInc := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "hotel_id": {
                S: aws.String(hotel_id),
            },
            "id": {
                S: aws.String(id),
            },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":val": {
                N: aws.String("1"),
            },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#update_count": aws.String("update_count"),
        },
        TableName:        aws.String(tableName),
        UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET #update_count = #update_count + :val"),
        ReturnValues: aws.String("UPDATED_NEW"),
    }

    w, err := db.UpdateItem(inputInc)
    fmt.Println("inputInc :", inputInc)
    fmt.Println("inputInc :", w)
    if err != nil {
        return be.ApiResponse(http.StatusBadRequest, be.ErrorBody{
            ErrorMsg: aws.String(errors.New(be.ErrorCouldNotDynamoPutItem).Error()),
        })
    }
```

Operation is successful and no error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    inputInc := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "hotel_id": {
                S: aws.String(hotel_id),
            },
            "id": {
                S: aws.String(id),
            },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":val": {
                N: 1
            },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#update_count": aws.String("update_count"),
        },
        TableName:        aws.String(tableName),
        UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET #update_count = #update_count + :val"),
        ReturnValues: aws.String("UPDATED_NEW"),
    }

    w, err := db.UpdateItem(inputInc)
    fmt.Println("inputInc :", inputInc)
    fmt.Println("inputInc :", w)
    if err != nil {
        return be.ApiResponse(http.StatusBadRequest, be.ErrorBody{
            ErrorMsg: aws.String(errors.New(be.ErrorCouldNotDynamoPutItem).Error()),
        })
    }
```

Have you tried change the ExpressionAttributeValues in just a number?

Comment: [Document](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.35.35/service/dynamodb#AttributeValue) says : Numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However, DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical operations.